# cannot generate view binders java.util.NoSuchElementException with Android Gradle Plugin 2.1

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-databinding

I'm using the binding mechanism in my Android project. All worked fine when using the Android Gradle Plugin until version 2.0.

Since a couple of days I can upgrade to version 2.1 of the Android Gradle Plugin. When I upgrade I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: failure, see logs for details.
cannot generate view binders java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at java.util.TreeMap$PrivateEntryIterator.nextEntry(TreeMap.java:1113)
        at java.util.TreeMap$KeyIterator.next(TreeMap.java:1169)
        at android.databinding.tool.store.SetterStore$1.compare(SetterStore.java:82)
        at android.databinding.tool.store.SetterStore$1.compare(SetterStore.java:60)
        at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:324)
        at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:189)
        at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:173)
        at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:659)
        at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:217)
        at android.databinding.tool.store.SetterStore.getMultiAttributeSetterCalls(SetterStore.java:473)
        at android.databinding.tool.BindingTarget.resolveMultiSetters(BindingTarget.java:203)
        at android.databinding.tool.LayoutBinder.<init>(LayoutBinder.java:238)
        at android.databinding.tool.DataBinder.<init>(DataBinder.java:52)
        at android.databinding.tool.CompilerChef.ensureDataBinder(CompilerChef.java:83)
        at android.databinding.tool.CompilerChef.sealModels(CompilerChef.java:168)
        at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessExpressions.writeResourceBundle(ProcessExpressions.java:149)
        at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessExpressions.onHandleStep(ProcessExpressions.java:82)
        at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding$ProcessingStep.runStep(ProcessDataBinding.java:154)
        at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding$ProcessingStep.access$000(ProcessDataBinding.java:139)
        at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding.process(ProcessDataBinding.java:66)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:793)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:722)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1700(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:97)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1029)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1163)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1108)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:824)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:439)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:132)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:45)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:33)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.delegateAndHandleErrors(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:103)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:38)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:34)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:25)
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.performCompilation(JavaCompile.java:157)
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:139)
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:93)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.AndroidJavaCompile.compile(AndroidJavaCompile.java:49)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:244)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:220)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:231)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:209)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:154)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:151)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:99)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:82)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:170)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
```

At the top there is a reference to a log file, but I have no idea which one. And there is no reference to any file in my project that is incorrect.

Does anyone have any idea what is going wrong or how I can resolve this error?

Comment: It's throwing during the annotation processing. Are you using any unusual annotations?

Comment: Not that I know of. But my project is quite big. If there is no pointer where to look it will be looking for a needle in a haystack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently somethings have changed related to events and databinding.
So far I've found these bindings that don't work after migrating to gradle 2.1

**1) EditText and onTextChanged:**

NOT WORKING SINCE GRADLE 2.1:

```
<EditText android:onTextChanged="@{binding.onTextChanged}" />

public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
```

THE FIX FOR EDITTEXT && TEXTWATCHER:

```
<EditText android:addTextChangedListener="@{binding.onTextChanged}" />

public TextWatcher onTextChanged = new SimpleTextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(String newBasic) {}
}
```

**2) SeekBar and onProgessChanged:**

NOT WORKING SINCE GRADLE 2.1:

```
<SeekBar android:onProgressChanged="@{viewModel.onSeekbarProgressChanged}" />

public void onSeekbarProgressChanged(@NonNull View _view, int progress, boolean _fromUser) {}
```

THE FIX FOR SEEKBAR&& PROGESSCHANGED:

```
<SeekBar android:onSeekBarChangeListener="@{viewModel.seekbarChanged}" />

public SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener seekbarChanged = new SimpleProgressChanged() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(final int progress) {
        .... your code
    }
};
```

Where SimpleTextWatcher:

```
public abstract class SimpleTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        onTextChanged(s.toString());
    }

    public abstract void onTextChanged(String newValue);
}
```

And SimpleProgressChanged:

```
public abstract class SimpleProgressChanged implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

    public abstract void onProgressChanged(int progress);

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(final SeekBar seekBar, final int progress,
        final boolean fromUser) {
        onProgressChanged(progress);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(final SeekBar seekBar) {}

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(final SeekBar seekBar) {}
}
```

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this bug. Can you provide a small sample with just one of these failures?

Answer (score 2):

Released with Android Studio 2.1 Preview 3, Android Data Binding now has 2-way data binding.

To make your binding two-way you'll only need to add one character:

> =

**Edit Text:**

One-Way Binding

```
<TextView android:text="@{user.firstName}" .../>
```

Two-Way Binding

```
<EditText android:text="@={user.firstName}" .../>
```

**Seek Bar**

One-Way Binding

```
<SeekBar android:progress="@{viewModel.angle}" .../>
```

Two-Way Binding

```
<SeekBar android:progress="@={viewModel.angle}" .../>
```

No need to set up listeners, etc. *It just works*.

[The only place I've found documentation is on this is at George Mount's (Android Engineer) blog.](https://halfthought.wordpress.com/2016/03/23/2-way-data-binding-on-android/)